# Can this Camera see near-infrared?

Tags: camera

The camera I'm talking about is here- https://www.amazon.ca/Raspberry-Pi-Camera-Filter-Vision/dp/B00KX3HS4K
My question is, is this camera a near-infrared camera?

Answer (score 3):

Yes but... It has no IR cut filter so it will image near infrared *and* visible light. This means that the colors in the visible light portion will be affected by the lack of an IR filter. The upside is that you can see in the dark using IR LED's to illuminate the scene. This CAN NOT see thermal images- that would be far infrared, and much more expensive.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way to make this camera ONLY see infrared? Can you block out the visible light spectrum?

Comment: Sure... Use an IR filter- I use one on my normal "everyday" camera. Most DSLR's can do IR photography because the IR cut filter on the sensor isn't as efficient as the IR pass filter you put in front of the lens. Exposures tend to be relatively long, but it can be done. See [here](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Infrared/ci/131/N/4026728332) for a large selection of various sizes. You may need to be creative for attaching it to the camera...